# Error when debugging my Laravel Application in VSCode using Xdebug

Tags: laravel, debugging, xdebug

I am trying to debug my Laravel application running with Sail using Xdebug in VSCode. But I am getting this error when debug my application.

[image]

Here is my `launch.json` file:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Is anyone know what is the problem for this? Thanks you so much!

Comment: That "Class App\Http\Controllers\Controller not found" error means that **you are doing the debugging wrong**. This usually happens when you are trying to execute or debug the controller file/class **directly**. This way you are **bypassing** the whole framework bootstrap logic and therefore no class autoloader in action. You need to debug the actual request (the URL) so it goes though your `index.php`, trough the whole framework code so that Laravel routes the execution to your controller where it will hit your breakpoint.

Comment: You can use "Listen for Xdebug" config. You would then need to either use Xdebug browser extension (that sets the Xdebug cookie that works as "debug me" flag) or configure Xdebug (php.ini) to try to debug _every single script/request_ with `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` (which is not the best approach overall but still a valid option).

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for your reply. As you suggested, I should place my breakpoint at actual request. Is't inside api.php(which is route file)? Or other file?

Comment: Place breakpoints where you need them. It's not about them. It's about the way you execute/access your controller code. The PHP must execute the whole request so it goes through the framework that will take you to the right place. Right now (based on the error) your are just trying to run/debug a single file directly, which is wrong. If it's a web page -- do it via browser (use the URL). If it's API -- use Postman or alike -- it' easier make API calls and see the response there.